# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not getting called on ios 10

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I've written this code in appDelegate

```
import UserNotifications
var registerId = String()
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.registerForPushNotifications(application)
    return true   
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }
    registerId = tokenString
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    if notificationSettings.types != .None {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
            if (granted)
            {
               application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
            else{
                registerId = "111111"
                //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
            }
        })
    }

    else{
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
            forTypes: [.Badge, .Sound, .Alert], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    }

}
}
```

With this code I'm able to get the device token in ios version < 10 , but for ios 10 and higher the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is not getting called. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One last thing, add framework:

```
import UserNotifications

class AppDelegate: /*Some other protocols I am extending...*/, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
...
    registerForPushNotifications(application)
...
}


    func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(granted, error) in
            if (granted)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
            else{
                //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
            }
        })
    }
    else { //If user is not on iOS 10 use the old methods we've been using
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
            types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    }

}
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

 }
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    //Handle the notification
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    //Handle the notification
}

}
```

Comment: @neha_mishra   thanks a bunch i don't which part was wrong in my code. but you surely helped me a lot with your responses.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from all these you have to enable your push notifications from capabilities.

Click on your project target you will see the screen and on capabilities enable push notifications.

[image]

Comment: Yes i've turned on Push notifications in capabilities.The func didFailToRegister i called up in simulator, but not on the device

Comment: Brother...in simulator it is not work..., if you use a device...it will work properly

Comment: @Gourav_Joshi  the function are called even if you don't get the token. didFailToRegister will be called in the simulator as well

Comment: have you create all necessary certificates for push notifications and pem files....?

Comment: @Gourav_Joshi yes i've created all necessary certificates and pem file and the notification is working in devices with ios version < 10

Answer (score 4):

Use this for ios 10 -

```
func registerForPushNotifications(_ application: UIApplication) {
      let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(
                types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
      if notificationSettings.types != UIUserNotificationType() {
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      }
}
func application( _ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data ) {

       var token: String = ""
       for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
           token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", deviceToken[i] as CVarArg)
       }

       UserDefaults.standard.setValue(token, forKey: "kDeviceToken")
       UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {}
```

PS:- Create proper certificate and bundle id also .Follow this tutorial -
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Use //Register for push Notifications

```
registerForPushNotifications(application)
```

in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method

Comment: i'm using swift 2.3 right now and created certificates and pem file properly.My code for ios 10 is not working correctly. Used your code still could not get the didRegisterForRemoteNotification called.

Comment: func registerForPushNotifications(_ application: UIApplication) { 

is this method called ?
Use debugger on did fail method also .

Comment: Yes this function gets called while the execution, used breakpoints to verify this.

Comment: I've device iPhone 5s with ios 10.1.1

Comment: Am creating new answer as I have implemented in my project please find .